# Keep spacing the same after getting value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a span and that span is content editable. So let's say... in the span... you write.

```
Hello,
My name is Ari.
```

When I ask the program to get the text from the span and alert it, it alerts:

```
"Hello,My name is Ari."
```

How do I get it so it keeps the spacing, or the indents I put in the content editable span when it prints it out. In other words, how do I get it so my program spits out

```
Hello,
My name is Ari.
```

Instead of:

```
Hello,My name is Ari.
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<span id="thirdspan" contenteditable="true">Write context text here:</span>
```

Here is the CSS:

Thanks!

Comment: How are you alerting the text from the span? Show us your JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Hello,<br />
My name is <span>Ari</span></p>
```

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/farondomenic/uCYs5/

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`<span class="output">Output Formatted Content</span>
      <div id="thirdspan" contenteditable="true" class="stuff" >Write context text here:</div>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span.output').click(function(){
      alert($('.stuff').html());
    });
  });
```